# Run VBS from powershell and capture the output

Tags: powershell

I have the following vb script code in the .vbs. I want to call the .vbs via powershell and capture the output of var1, var2 & var3 in the powershell.

```
public function GenerateResponseFile()

    Dim objServiceLogon 
    Dim var1
    Dim var2
    Dim var3

    var1 = ""
    var2=""
    var3=""

    set objServiceLogon = CreateObject("DSServiceLogonCOM.CoServiceLogon")
    objServiceLogon.DSGetDetails "ABCSVC", "ABCDE", var1, var2, var3

End function
```

Comment: If that is the sum total of your vbscript, I suggest you simply right it directly in powershell.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be much easier to rewrite the script into PowerShell.

Assuming the library is registered:

```
$var1 = ''
$var2 = ''
$var3 = ''
$objServiceLogon = New-Object -ComObject "DSServiceLogonCOM.CoServiceLogon"
$objServiceLogon.DsGetDetails("ABCSVC", "ABCDE", $var1, $var2, $var3)
```

MS has [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/creating-.net-and-com-objects--new-object-?view=powershell-5.1) on working with COM object.

Otherwise, if you just want to capture the text output you could try:

```
$Output = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath 'C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe' -ArgumentList 'MyScript.vbs', '//B', '//NoLogo'
```

Or:

```
Start-Process -Wait -OutVariable Output -FilePath 'C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe' -ArgumentList 'MyScript.vbs', '//B', '//NoLogo'
$Output
```

Comment: I tried to run it from powershell as you have specified. But I am not getting the values of the output variables var1, var2 & var3 back to powershell. It is still coming as blank.

Comment: Oh, they're *output* variables?  In that case, try `$objServiceLogon.DsGetDetails("ABCSVC", "ABCDE", ([ref]$var1), ([ref]$var2), ([ref]$var3))`.  PowerShell uses pass by value by default.  I don't know if that will work for a COM object, however.  You really might need to call the VBScript.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This didn't work. So I have written the output inot a file in the vb script itself and have called the vb script in powershell and used the output for further processing.